# Python Flask & HTML - Control motors with html sliders

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have a RaspberryPi car and I want to control it using two motors. I want to do this by using HTML sliders with Flask.

I'm having issues because I'm not sure how to dynamically send the current motor slider values to Flask. Here's what I have tried so far, the issue is that the page resets after POST. I have a feeling there's a better way to do this, if so please can you help, Thanks.

HTML Form:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('welcome') }}"  id="motorSliderForm" method="POST">
    <input name="leftMotorSlider" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" oninput="leftMotor(this.value)" value={{leftMotorValue}}>
    <span id="leftMotorValBox"></span>
    <br>
    <input name="rightMotorSlider" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" oninput="rightMotor(this.value)" value={{rightMotorValue}}>
    <span id="rightMotorValBox"></span>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function leftMotor(newVal){
document.getElementById("leftMotorValBox").innerHTML=newVal;
document.getElementById("motorSliderForm").submit();
}

function rightMotor(newVal){
document.getElementById("rightMotorValBox").innerHTML=newVal;
document.getElementById("motorSliderForm").submit();
}
```

Python Flask code:

```
leftMotor = 10
rightMotor = 10

@app.route("/", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def welcome():
    global leftMotor
    global rightMotor

    if request.method == 'POST':
        leftMotor = request.form.get("leftMotorSlider")
        rightMotor = request.form.get("rightMotorSlider")
        print("left motor: {}, right motor: {}".format(leftMotor, rightMotor))
    return render_template(
        "welcome.html",
        leftMotorValue=leftMotor,
        rightMotorValue = rightMotor,
    )
```

Comment: What you'll want to do is separate the logic for handling `post` and `get` request into different end-points. Then from javascript side you'll send a post request to that end point whenever the slider value changes.

Answer (score 0):

Split your **index** route and your **update** route in your **flask application**:

```py
leftMotor = 10
rightMotor = 10

@application.route('/', methods=["GET"])
def index():

    return render_template('index.html', rightMotor=rightMotor,
                                         leftMotor=leftMotor)

@application.route('/updateMotorValue', methods=["POST"])
def updateMotorValue():

    msg = ""
    if request.json["motor"] == "left":
        leftMotor = int(request.json["value"])
        msg = "leftMotor has been updated with value {}".format(request.json["value"])
    elif request.json["motor"] == "right":
        rightMotor = int(request.json["value"])
        msg = "rightMotor has been updated with value {}".format(request.json["value"])

    return jsonify(msg)
```

Every time a slider value changes, an asynchronous **POST** request is made via [**fetch()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) updating the value in the application. This way the page is not refreshed every time a **POST** request is made. We then return a message in the console telling which motor has been updated and its new value.

```js
var sliders = {};

(function () {

    var CSRFToken;

    this.setCSRFToken = function(t) {
        CSRFToken = t;
    }

    this.updateMotorValue = async function (motor, value) {
        try {
            const response = await fetch("/updateMotorValue", {
                method: 'POST',
                mode: 'cors',
                cache: 'no-cache',
                credentials: 'same-origin',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'X-CSRFToken': CSRFToken
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({"motor": motor, "value": value})
            })
            console.log(await response.json());
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };

}).apply(sliders);
```

Note that we don't need a **<form>** anymore.

```html
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='sliders.js') }}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                            sliders.setCSRFToken('{{ csrf_token() }}');
                        });
</script>
<div id="motorSliders">
    <input name="leftMotorSlider" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" oninput="sliders.updateMotorValue('left', this.value)" value={{leftMotor}}>
    <span id="leftMotorValBox"></span>
    <br>
    <input name="rightMotorSlider" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" oninput="sliders.updateMotorValue('right', this.value)" value={{rightMotor}}>
    <span id="rightMotorValBox"></span>
</div>
```

Don't forget to pass the **CSRF token** to your js file so that you can make **POST** requests.